# i want to find details of file that i created and print it to the screen i'm using perl

Tags: perl

```
my $filesize = -s "infile.txt";

use File::stat;
use Time::localtime;

$file='infile.txt';
$date_string = ctime(stat($file)->mtime);

print "file $file updated at $date_string\n";
print "Size: $filesize\n";

exit 0;
```

thank you.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Your code works fine and shows file update time and size. What details do you want exactly?

Comment: how can i find details of file that i created previous i want to display the date and details to the screen

Comment: Could you be more specific as to sorts of file details you want?  You already display the date the file size...

Comment: it must display in user friendly format

Comment: Please edit your question to include... well, a question, I suppose. It looks to me like your code already does what you want it to. So you need to explain exactly how it falls short. Perhaps give an example of the output you're getting and the the output you want.

Answer (score 1):

It's really not clear what is wrong with your existing code. It seems to do what you want. Our only clue is a comment where you say "it must display in user friendly format" without bothering to explain what a "user friendly format" is.

So I'm going to guess that you don't like the date/time format that `ctime` gives you. And, of course, you don't need to stick with that format. If you swap your use of Time::localtime for Time::Piece, then you can use the `strftime` method to get the date/time in any format  that you want.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use File::stat;
use Time::Piece;

my $format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S';

my $file='infile.txt';

my $filesize = -s $file;

my $date_string = localtime(stat($file)->mtime)->strftime($format);

print "file $file updated at $date_string\n";
print "Size: $filesize\n";
```

The format that I've used is just an example. You can use any of the escape sequences supported by [strftime](http://www.manpages.info/linux/strftime.3.html).